# Variable contains backslash not working in sed bash

Tags: bash, sed

Our log pattern is in the following format dd/Mon/year:time(22/Feb/2018:13).

Goal is we want to find logs between 2 different times. We used sed to get the log between 2 times.

```
 sed -n '/22\/Feb\/2018:13:/,/22\/Feb\/2018:16/p' /var/log/apache2/domlogs/access.log
```

The above command is working manually. We created a two variables called **LAST** and **NOW** in the script and assigned the date variables as mentioned below.

```
NOW="22/Feb/2018:16"

LAST="22/Feb/2018:13"
```

We have used the following sed commands to print the same output however it doesn't help us to print the same output.

```
sed -n '/'"$LAST"'/'"$NOW"'/p' /var/log/apache2/domlogs/access.log
```

The command gives the below error
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `F'

If we use normal string for **LAST** and **NOW** then above command works fine. Only problem is if the variable contains / in the input

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407523/escape-a-string-for-a-sed-replace-pattern

Comment: Yes; you aren't passing variables to a `sed` script, you are dynamically *creating* a `sed` script, so it is your responsibility to escape anything in the values of `NOW` and `LAST` so that the resulting script is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can freely change your delimiter of sed's regular expression by preceding it with a backslash, e.g. `\!`. Following command should work:

```
sed -n '\!'"$LAST"'!,\!'"$NOW"'!p' /var/log/apache2/domlogs/access.log
```

If `!` is expected to show up in your date time format, you can use your judgment to choose another one.

You should read some good sed tutorial before working with sed, e.g.: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/sed.html

---

I think you originally want to implement a range search in `sed` while you might miss the syntax of that. I fixed it above and it's tested.

Comment: Also his strings are datetimes and have colons

Comment: @GillesQuenot a leading `\\` will allow sed to set a different delimiter.

Comment: @zzxyz I just fixed my brain. in fact, any character that does not appear in datetime format will work. it has nothing to do with file system.